# Lightbox gallery widget opens the image in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, dreamweaver, lightbox

I've been using the lightbox gallery widget on my website to create picture galleries. But it opens the image in a new window instead of in a lightbox. It works fine on a blank site, but not on any of my webpages. My guess is that there is a conflict with some other javascript file I've used (my pages use javascript for SpryMenu-s and for a responsive side menu bar that shows up on smaller screen sizes.) I haven't changed any code for the lightbox and have allowed dreamweaver to insert the stylesheets and scripts automatically.

I've looked up this problem and I don't seem to have any of the problems mentioned in other answers. All my images, stylesheets and scripts seem to be linked correctly. The gallery div has been linked to the correct classes. I can't seem to figure out where the problem is.

This is one of the pages on website that uses the gallery: http://ruchikanambiar.com/Projects/scenes.html

This is my HTML code for the above page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>Ruchika Nambiar | Scenes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SpryAssets/slidebars.min.css">
<link href="../CSS Stylesheets/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    color: #D6D6D6;
    background-image: url(../Image/patt-01.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
</style>
<link href="../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../favicon-01.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
<style type="text/css">
a:link {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F03;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F03;
}
</style>
<link href="../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/sample_lightbox_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-33584208-1', 'ruchikanambiar.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<style type="text/css">
/* BeginOAWidget_Instance_2127022: #gallery */

        .lbGallery { 
            /*gallery container settings*/
            background-color: transparent;
            padding-left: 10px;  
            padding-top: 10px;  
            padding-right: 10px;  
            padding-bottom: 10px;  
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            text-align:left;
        }
        .lbGallery ul { list-style: none; margin:0;padding:0; }
        .lbGallery ul li { display: inline;margin:0;padding:0; }
        .lbGallery ul li a{text-decoration:none;}

        .lbGallery ul li a img {
            /*border color, width and margin for the images*/
            border-color: transparent;
            border-left-width: 1px;
            border-top-width: 1px;
            border-right-width: 1px;
            border-bottom-width: 1px;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-right:0px;
            margin-top:0px;
            margin-bottom:0px:
            }

        .lbGallery ul li a:hover img {  
            /*background color on hover*/
            border-color: #ffffff;
            border-left-width: 1px;
            border-top-width: 1px;
            border-right-width: 1px;
            border-bottom-width: 1px;
        }

        #lightbox-container-image-box {
            border-top: 0px none #ffffff;
            border-right: 0px none #ffffff;
            border-bottom: 0px none #ffffff;
            border-left: 0px none #ffffff;
            }

        #lightbox-container-image-data-box { 
            border-top: 0px;
            border-right: 0px none #ffffff;
            border-bottom: 0px none #ffffff;
            border-left: 0px none #ffffff;
            }
/* EndOAWidget_Instance_2127022 */
</style>
<script type="text/xml">
<!--
<oa:widgets>
  <oa:widget wid="2127022" binding="#gallery" />
</oa:widgets>
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sb-site">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="toplinks"><a href="../Home.html"><img src="../Image/toplink-01.png" width="17" height="15" alt="Home"/></a> <a href="../Contact.html"><img src="../Image/toplink-02.png" width="22" height="17" alt="Contact" /></a></div>
  <div id="top">
    <div id="logopic"><img src="../Image/Logo-01.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" /></div>
    <div id="logo">RUCHIKA NAMBIAR</div>
    <div id="menu">
    <div class="sb-toggle-right">
        <div class="navicon-line"></div>
        <div class="navicon-line"></div>
        <div class="navicon-line"></div>
    </div>
      <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
        <li><a href="../Home.html" title="Home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="../About.html" title="About">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Projects.html" title="Projects" class='MenuBarItemActive'>PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Graphic Design.html" title="Graphic Design">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Resume.html" title="Resume">RÉSUMÉ</a></li>
        <div align="right"></div>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="mainleft">PROJECTS<br />
      <br />
      <ul id="MenuBar2" class="MenuBarVertical">
        <li><a href="the-breadcrumb.html">The Breadcrumb</a></li>
        <li><a href="grandma-wars.html">Grandma Wars</a></li>
        <li><a href="living-library.html">The Living Library of Dystopia</a></li>
        <li><a href="scenes.html" class='MenuBarItemActive'>Scenes</a></li>
        <li><a href="sibling-book.html">The Little Book of Sibling Love</a></li>
        <li><a href="invisible-cities.html">Illustrated Invisible Cities</a></li>
        <li><a href="above-is-below.html">Above is Below Diorama</a></li>
        <li><a href="fountainhead-fonts.html">Fountainhead Fonts</a></li>
        <li><a href="type-factory.html">Type Factory</a></li>
        <li><a href="misandry-spelt-backwards.html">Misandry Spelt Backwards</a></li>
        <li><a href="royalty-cards.html">Royalty Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="cry-animation.html">C.R.Y Animation</a></li>
        <li><a href="adventures.html">The Adventures of Time & Circumstance</a></li>
        <li><a href="storybookme-video.html">Storybook Me Video</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mainright">
      <div id="hiddenheader">PROJECTS</div>
      <div id="projecthead">Scenes</div>
      <div id="prevnext"><a href="living-library.html">&lt;PREV</a> | <a href="sibling-book.html">NEXT&gt;</a></div>
      ILLUSTRATED CARDS DEPICTING MEMORIES: Work in progress<br />
      <br />
This project is an attempt to build and cement memory, in the form of illustrated snapshots that depict  “scenes” from my own life, which once put together, can create a metaphoric stopmotion of my life. The intention is to create an ever-growing collection of cards.<br />
      <br />
      <div id="rightcontent">
        <div id="gallery" class="lbGallery">
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/1.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/1.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/2.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/2.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/3.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/3.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/4.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/4.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/5.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/5.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/6.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/6.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/7.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/7.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/8.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/8.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/9.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/9.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/10.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/10.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/11.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/11.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/12.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/12.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/13.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/13.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/14.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/14.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> <a href="../Image/FullImages/Projects/New folder (3)/15.jpg"><img src="../Image/Thumbnails/Projects/New folder (3)/15.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72" /></a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
// BeginOAWidget_Instance_2127022: #gallery

        $(function(){
            $('#gallery a').lightBox({ 
                imageLoading:           '../images/lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif',      // (string) Path and the name of the loading icon
                imageBtnPrev:           '../images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',         // (string) Path and the name of the prev button image
                imageBtnNext:           '../images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-next.gif',         // (string) Path and the name of the next button image
                imageBtnClose:          '../images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif',        // (string) Path and the name of the close btn
                imageBlank:             '../images/lightbox/lightbox-blank.gif',            // (string) Path and the name of a blank image (one pixel)
                fixedNavigation:        true,       // (boolean) Boolean that informs if the navigation (next and prev button) will be fixed or not in the interface.
                containerResizeSpeed:   400,             // Specify the resize duration of container image. These number are miliseconds. 400 is default.
                overlayBgColor:         "#999999",      // (string) Background color to overlay; inform a hexadecimal value like: #RRGGBB. Where RR, GG, and BB are the hexadecimal values for the red, green, and blue values of the color.
                overlayOpacity:         .6,     // (integer) Opacity value to overlay; inform: 0.X. Where X are number from 0 to 9
                txtImage:               'Image',                //Default text of image
                txtOf:                  'of'
            });
        });

// EndOAWidget_Instance_2127022
        </script>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
<br />
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="like">
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://ruchikanambiar.com/" data-width="100px" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="copyright">&copy; Ruchika Nambiar</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</div>
<div class="sb-slidebar sb-right">
    <nav>
      <div id="sidetopbar"><a href="../Home.html"><img src="../Image/Logo-01.png" width="80" height="80" alt="logo" /></a></div>
      <p><a href="../Home.html" title="Home">HOME</a></p>
      <p><a href="../About.html" title="About">ABOUT</a></p>
      <p><a href="../Projects.html" title="Projects">PROJECTS</a></p>
      <p><a href="../Graphic Design.html" title="Graphic Design">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></p>
      <p><a href="../Resume.html" title="Resume">RÉSUMÉ</a></p>
      <div id="sidemiddlebar"></div>
      <p><a href="../Journal.html" title="Journal">JOURNAL</a></p>
      <p><a href="../Contact.html" tite="Contact">CONTACT</a></p>      
    </nav>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../SpryAssets/slidebars.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var mySlidebars = new $.slidebars();
      $('.my-button').on('click', function() {
        mySlidebars.open('left');
      });
      $('.my-other-button').on('click', function() {
        mySlidebars.toggle('right');
      });
      $('.my-third-button').click(mySlidebars.close);
    });
  }) (jQuery);
var MenuBar2 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar2", {imgRight:"../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a dummy link?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. A dummy link? This is one of the webpages that uses the lightbox gallery: http://ruchikanambiar.com/Projects/scenes.html

Comment: Can you try adding the new jquery files. I see they are bit old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your page and did exact step, that solved my problem:

So:

```
 //$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#gallery a').lightBox({ 
            imageLoading:           '../images/lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif',      // (string) Path and the name of the loading icon
            imageBtnPrev:           '../images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',         // (string) Path and the name of the prev button image
            imageBtnNext:           '../images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-next.gif',         // (string) Path and the name of the next button image
            imageBtnClose:          '../images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif',        // (string) Path and the name of the close btn
            imageBlank:             '../images/lightbox/lightbox-blank.gif',            // (string) Path and the name of a blank image (one pixel)
            fixedNavigation:        true,       // (boolean) Boolean that informs if the navigation (next and prev button) will be fixed or not in the interface.
            containerResizeSpeed:   400,             // Specify the resize duration of container image. These number are miliseconds. 400 is default.
            overlayBgColor:         "#999999",      // (string) Background color to overlay; inform a hexadecimal value like: #RRGGBB. Where RR, GG, and BB are the hexadecimal values for the red, green, and blue values of the color.
            overlayOpacity:         .6,     // (integer) Opacity value to overlay; inform: 0.X. Where X are number from 0 to 9
            txtImage:               'Image',                //Default text of image
            txtOf:                  'of'
        });
    //});
```

**remove or comment out the lines of $(document).ready(function(){**

and it will work. :D

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is old. I tried the same thing on your project with new jquery loading (using getScript). It started to work. Hence the solution is "Add a new jQuery". But with that $.browser issue is raised as it not supported.

Comment: Thanks so much, but could you explain exactly where I need to make this change and how to go about it?
I don't use jquery much and I don't want to mess anything up by inserting something in the wrong place. 
But it seems you've located the problem, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Go about the issue of light box?

Comment: BTW please mark the answer right if you feel its right. This would remove the question from the stackoverflows unanswered queue.

Comment: @SSS It is not a JQuery old problem, and not the right answer :P

Comment: @user3659114 I had a similar issues a while back and I am posting my asnwer, it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior No problems. Eager to see the answer. My day to learn something new :D

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior Sure, thanks a lot! This issue has been annoying me a great deal for the past few days.

Comment: @user3659114 For the latest jquery you can add this in your jquery script call src http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js and for other latest jquery cdn(Hosted Online) try this link https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide